# Sublime Text 3: Open file in read-only mode directly upon opening

Tags: sublime-text-3, read-only, sublime-text

I'm trying to find a way to force ST 3 into opening a file directly into read-only mode.  I'm aware of plugins like [toggle-readonly](https://github.com/reflog/toggle-readonly), but that requires user interaction and can be easily forgotten.

Does anyone know how to open file in ST3 directly in **read-only mode without any user interaction**?

**Edit:**

I have opened a [feature request](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/4582) on SublimeText's github.